# MVC Unable to pass value to the one of 2 parameters on URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an index view listing a list of records. I have 2 datepicker fields (FromDate, ToDate) which I use to allow users to filter data on the list. The first time users access the page, there's no values in FromDate and ToDate to pass to action

```
Index(DateTime? fd, DateTime? td)
```

so I use default values

```
fromDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7); // and
toDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(14);
```

Once the Index view load with default data, users can now use the date fields to change the date range. Every time users click search, I will pass the values from 2 date fields to the Index action in my controller using url. However, the first value (fd) is not passed to the controller. The 2nd value (td) is passed to the controller correctly. What I do wrong? Or there's a better approach/best practice to do this?

My Index view:

```
<a id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-info" href="/Slide/Index/?fd=@ViewBag.FromDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")&td=@ViewBag.ToDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")"> Search </a>

<div class="input-group date">
      <span>From: </span>@Html.TextBox("FromDate", (DateTime)ViewBag.FromDate, new { @class = "col-md-6", @style="width:80px" })
</div>
<div class="input-group date">
      <span>From: </span>@Html.TextBox("ToDate", (DateTime)ViewBag.ToDate, new { @class = "col-md-6", @style="width:80px" })
</div>

<div class="row">
    <table class="table table-hover" style="width:auto" id="sTable">
       //this is where I list the result data here....
    </table>
</div><!--End of row-->
```

My routes:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Slide",
        url: "Slide/Index/{fd}/{td}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Slide", action = "Index", fd = UrlParameter.Optional, td = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

}
```

And action method:

```
public ActionResult Index(DateTime? fd = null, DateTime? td = null)
{
    DateTime fromDate;
    DateTime toDate;

    if (!fd.HasValue)
        fromDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);
    else
        fromDate = fd.Value;

    if (!td.HasValue)
        toDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(14);
    else
        toDate = td.Value;

    IEnumerable<EZone_SlideInfo> lSlide = _slideRepo.GetSlideByExpiration(fromDate, toDate);

    ViewBag.FromDate = DateTime.Parse(fromDate.ToShortDateString());
    ViewBag.ToDate = DateTime.Parse(toDate.ToShortDateString());

    return View(lSlide);
}
```

Comment: You can only have the last parameter being optional so remove `fd = UrlParameter.Optional` from the route and change the method to `Index(DateTime fd, DateTime? td)` (and if your always passing 2 dates, then your should do the same for `td` (i.e. not nullable)

Comment: Its also not clear which view your `<a id="btnSearch" ..>` is associated with. If its the `Index()` method, then your assigning the `ViewBag` properties for `FromDate` and `ToDate` as strings to `fd=@ViewBag.FromDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")` would not work (its already a string, not a `DateTime`)

Comment: @Stephen: please see my update. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `/` before the `?` - it should be

```
<a id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-info" href="/Slide/Index?fd=@ViewBag.....`,
```

However your hard coding the url based on `ViewBag` properties, so your textboxes don't do anything (their values are never sent to the controller method) so your view will only ever display records between today - 7 days and today + 14 days. Also

```
ViewBag.FromDate = DateTime.Parse(fromDate.ToShortDateString());
```

is pointless - your converting a date to a string and then converting it back to a date. In addition you route defaults should be `defaults: new { controller = "Slide", action = "Index" }` i.e. no optional parameters.

If your wanting to filter records based on the selection of 2 dates, you need to post a form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Slide", FormMethod.Get))
{
  // you textboxes/datepickers
  <input type="submit" .../>
}
```

so that you post the selected values back to the method. You should be using a view model with properties for the dates and the collection

```
public class SearchVM
{
  public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
  public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<EZone_SlideInfo> Records { get; set; }
}
```

and then in your view

```
@model SearchVM
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Slide", FormMethod.Get))
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromDate)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ToDate)
  <input type="submit" .../>
}
<table>
  @foreach(var item in Model.Records)
  {
    // display your filtered results
```

and the controller method

```
public ActionResult Index(DateTime? fromDate, DateTime? toDate) // no need for '= null'
{
  fromDate = fromDate ?? DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);
  toDate = toDate ?? DateTime.Today.AddDays(14);
  ModelState.Clear();
  SearchVM model = new SearchVM()
  {
    FromDate = fromDate,
    ToDate = toDate,
    Records = _slideRepo.GetSlideByExpiration(fromDate.Value, toDate.Value);
  };
  return View(model);
}
```

And of course your could improve performance by using javascript/jquery and ajax to post the selected dates to a controller method that returns only the filtered results to avoid having to regenerate the view each time.

Answer (score 0):

Your **hard-coded** query string `fd=@ViewBag.FromDate&td=@ViewBag.ToDate` is:

1. error prone especially if you need to do encode URL for special characters
2. hard to read and maintain.

As a best practice, consider using the [`Html.ActionLink()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary%7BSystem.String,System.Object%7D%29) or [`Html.RouteLink()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.routelink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.RouteLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary%7BSystem.String,System.Object%7D%29) extension methods so it won't be broken if the URL Routing pattern changes (or) needs URL encoding.

```
@{
    // This code block can be put at the VERY TOP of the .cshtml view.
    // That way, it doesn't clutter up your HTML source code potion with C# code.

    var searchRouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary {
                                { "fd", ViewBag.FromDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") },
                                { "td", ViewBag.ToDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") }
                            };

    var btnSearchHtmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object> {
                                      { "class", "btn btn-info" },
                                      { "id",    "btnSearch" }
                                  };
}

<!-- using ActionLink extension method -->
@Html.ActionLink(
    linkText       : "Search",
    actionName     : "Index",
    controller     : "Slide",
    routeValues    : searchRouteValues,
    htmlAttributes : btnSearchHtmlAttributes
)

<!-- using RouteLink extension method -->
@Html.RouteLink(
    linkText       : "Search",
    routeName      : "Slide" /* NOTICE: this requires CUSTOM route registration */,
    routeValues    : searchRouteValues,
    htmlAttributes : btnSearchHtmlAttributes
)
```

Do you ACTUALLY need a pretty-looking URL as you wrote below?

```
// your code
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Slide",
    url: "Slide/Index/{fd}/{td}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Slide", action = "Index", fd = UrlParameter.Optional, td = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

If not, keep it as generic as possible like below.

```cs
// default/generic route registration code
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

And your URL Route will still work correctly as long as you are using the `Html.ActionLink()` as I showed above. It will render the hyperlink like this.

```
<a id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-info"
   href="/Slide/?fd=01/01/2015&to=01/02/2015">Search</a>
```

If you rewrite your code as I showed above, I am certain it will fix your issue.

Comment: Sorry everyone, my computer was down after I posted the question so I could not try your suggestion. I have updated my question to clarify my problem. My apology for any confusion.